# how to get dictionaries from a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
"uses":{"permitted":[
{"end_time":"2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00","use":"park","vehicle_type":"all"},
{"end_time":"2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00","use":"load_goods","vehicle_type":"all"},
{"end_time":"2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00","use":"load_passengers","vehicle_type":"all"}
],
"use":"park","vehicle_type":"all"}}
```

"uses" has 'permitted', 'use' and 'vehicle_type' as keys. But 'permitted' has a list if dictionaries inside it. I was getting keys and putting the data into the column. But now I can't get data as keys from permitted.

Comment: Invalid syntax. Please clean it up so it can be run and used.

Comment: Show your attempt...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'uses': {'permitted': [{'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                             'use': 'park',
                             'vehicle_type': 'all'},
                            {'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                             'use': 'load_goods',
                             'vehicle_type': 'all'},
                            {'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                             'use': 'load_passengers',
                             'vehicle_type': 'all'}],
              'use': 'park',
              'vehicle_type': 'all'}}

d['uses']['permitted'] = {x['use'] : {k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != 'use'} for x in d['uses']['permitted']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d['uses']['permitted']).transpose()
```

Which gives:

```
>>> d
{'uses': {'permitted': {'load_goods': {'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                                       'vehicle_type': 'all'},
                        'load_passengers': {'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                                            'vehicle_type': 'all'},
                        'park': {'end_time': '2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00',
                                 'vehicle_type': 'all'}},
          'use': 'park',
          'vehicle_type': 'all'}}
>>> df
                                      end_time vehicle_type
park             2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00          all
load_goods       2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00          all
load_passengers  2019-02-27T17:22:44.663-05:00          all
```